# Sub-table obtained by vector or keys in R

Tags: r

I have a table (`tbl`) like following one:

```
ID    VAL
foo   sometext
bar   anothertext
boo   text
foor  texttext   
...
```

And a vector of IDs (`vect`), sub-vector of `tbl$ID`

```
bar
foo
...
```

I need to make new table (sub-table of `tbl`), where key are only from `vect`. How can I perform this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple better options than a `data.frame` for key-value pairs.

First, though, make sure you're using character strings, not factors:

```
tbl[] <- lapply(tbl,as.character)
```

---

(1) Use a keyed data.table:

```
require(data.table)
setkey(setDT(tbl),ID)
tbl[J(vect)]
#     ID         VAL
# 1: bar anothertext
# 2: foo    sometext
```

(2) Use a named vector:

```
tblvec <- setNames(tbl$VAL,tbl$ID)
tblvec[vect]
#           bar           foo 
# "anothertext"    "sometext"
```

(3) If you want something like a hash, [@JoshuaUlrich's answer here](http://@JoshuaUlrich's%20answer%20here) says that you can use an `environment`. Also, there is a `hash` package.

Comment: @downvoter and other so inclined: go ahead, not that I understand where you're coming from at all.

Comment: (2) work perfect. However in (1) I have got `Error: could not find function "setkey"` (+1)

Comment: @Loom If you install `data.table` first, then the first line here `require(data.table)` should load the `setkey` function. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
tbl <- data.frame(ID=c('foo','bar','boo','foor'), VAL=c('sometext','anothertext','text','texttext') );
vect <- c('bar','foo');
tbl[tbl$ID%in%vect,];
##    ID         VAL
## 1 foo    sometext
## 2 bar anothertext
```

Another approach:

```
subset(tbl,ID%in%vect);
##    ID         VAL
## 1 foo    sometext
## 2 bar anothertext
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use subset function and it will give you data tbl based on ID's that are only in vect

```
subsets <- subset(tbl , ID %in% vect )
```

It will check the tbl$ID that are in vect and give you the sub table for those ID's only.

Comment: Typo: you called `subset` the "Subsets" function. Also, you can go with the simpler `subset(tbl , ID %in% vect )`

Comment: @akrun Yeah, I just realized it's a dupe after editing.